# Lemon Balm Uses

Tags: culinary-uses, herbs

It's growing like a weed, and has a wonderful smell just wondering what I can use it for in the kitchen?

Comment: In addition to any specific suggestions, just remember that you have it. You might find yourself cooking something and think "this could use a hint of lemon". Don't be afraid to experiment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make a pesto out of it. Goes well with fish and chicken
- Use it in a Mediterranean-style stuffing, along with feta cheese, garlic and sundried tomatoes
- Rip up and toss through salads
- Make a herbal tea
- Make ice cream

Answer (score 1):

Make jelly. I can't remember the recipe exactly, but it's something along the lines of:

- juice and zest a couple of lemons
- steep lemonbalm and lemon zest in hot water to extract the flavour
- mix infusion and lemon juice together
- sweeten to taste
- add gelatine
- pour into suitable vessels, chill to set
- eat

The lemonbalm gives you a different kind of lemonyness than lemons alone do, so the resulting jelly has a deeper flavour.